# How to hide collapsible-header when collapsible-content is displayed in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on Jquery Mobile and I am using collapsible set. When I click h3, then collapsible-content is diplayed. this is pre defined. But what I need is, When I click h3(Animals), then h3 should be hidden and only ul should be diplayed(Cats). Likewise if I click on the image inside ul(Cats panel), this should be hidden and header-h3 should be displayed. I have a large set of data in this way and want to apply to the entire set.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/K2HQG/2/)**

```
//html
    <div id="list" data-role="collapsibleset" data-inset="false">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Animals</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                <li><span><img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/"></span>Cats</li>          
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried if `<details open=""></details>` would do its job and relay on javascript only as a fallback ?  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/details

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K2HQG/3/ with basic 'details' tag

Comment: why did u include details? i don't need extra details tag in this set. You also lost the accordion effect in this- if one panel opens the other should be closed.

Comment: because details is there to be click and toggled open/closed natively without javascript to show what ever is behind the title included, it is forgotten or unknown by most, data-role could even be skip in that case, because it is a collapsing element itself. If to turn the div into a semnatic tag for the purpose you need makes this work better , why not ?

Answer (score 1):

As @falsarella notes, you can achieve the hiding of the `h3` through CSS, but restoring it and hiding the child `ul` when clicking the image will require some jQuery click handlers. Example:

```
$(function () {
    $('div[data-role="collapsible"] > h3').click(function() {
        if(!$(this).is(':hidden'))
            $(this).hide();
    });
    $('ul[data-role="listview"] img').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]').children('h3').trigger('click').show();
    });
});
```

Updated jsFiddle, forked from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/dBH3h/

The click handler on the `div[data-role="collapsible"] > h3` handles the work of hiding the `h3` upon expanding it; the IF condition therein is then leveraged by the next handler.

By attaching to the click event for your `ul[data-role="listview"] img`, we can then use some basic DOM traversal in jQ to find the associated `h3`, trigger its clink event (which automatically hides the `ul` and restores the expand icon) and then make it visible again.

UPDATE: Because this particular collapsible widget does not support having multiple panels open at once, this answer can cause unexpected results (i.e. multiple hidden headers) when attempting to expand a new one before collapsing the previous one. For widgets where that's not the case, this would work - for this widget, look to Omar's answer.

Comment: I'd also note you could debate whether checking the `.is(':hidden')` state of the `h3` in the first click handler is worth it; the idea being to save an unnecessary DOM change (i.e. why run `.hide()` against something already hidden). As such, the IF condition could be removed if so desired and not affect the functionality.

Comment: there is some error in ur answer. if i click on the other panels they all r getting disappeared.

Comment: My apologies, I did not realize the collapsible you're using does not support having more than one section open at a time. Omar's answer works for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to `collapsibleexpand` event and then hide header by adding `ui-screen-hidden` class. To show the header again, you need to bind an event to collapsible's content. E.g. A `click` event will show header again and *collapse* content programmatically `.collapsible("collapse")`.

```
$(document).on("collapsibleexpand", "[data-role=collapsibleset]", function (e) {
   // show previously hidden headers
   $(".ui-screen-hidden").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
   // hide target collapsible's header
   $("h3", e.target).addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
   // listen to click event on collapsible's content
}).on("click", ".ui-collapsible-content", function () {
   // retrieve parent collapsible 
   var collapsible = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible");
   // show header
   collapsible.find(".ui-screen-hidden").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
   // collapse target collapsible 
   collapsible.collapsible("collapse");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9GAxF/)**

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following **CSS**:

```
.ui-collapsible h3 {
    display: none;
}

.ui-collapsible.ui-collapsible-collapsed h3 {
    display: block;
}
```

And the following **JS**:

```
$(".ui-collapsible-content").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().collapsible("collapse");
});
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K2HQG/6/) so you can verify whether it is the desired behavior or not.

Comment: Nice quick CSS to hide the `h3` on click but it does not address this requirement from the OP: "Likewise if I click on the image inside ul(Cats panel), this should be hidden and header-h3 should be displayed"

Comment: @Stevangelista Thank you for pointing this out, I have updated my answer to address the missing requirement.